# JavaFX SceneBuilder won't launch

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder, gluon

I just installed SceneBuilder from Gluon and I can't launch it... It installed correctly (I noticed the installer didn't reach the end.... but all files were correctly in AppData/Local) I tried to launch the EXE but it won't do anything. It doesn't show any errors or anything, it just won't launch....
Anyone ?

Comment: Installer should have finished. Can you uninstall and install again? If it doesn't work you may try running the installer as administrator. Which is your Windows version?

Comment: Windows 10... ill try reinstall

Comment: I reinstalled as admin and it still closed before end...

Comment: Can you check the installation folder, and see if you have an `app` folder with an executable `dist.jar`? If you have Java installed you could run it just by double clicking on it.

Comment: It works! But if I want to run it from .exe I can't ? So in IntelliJ I can link the jar ?

Comment: in eclipse u have to link it.. dont know about intellij tough

Comment: The exe should work, maybe some dlls weren't installed for any reason. You can download it again, and try to reinstall it?

Comment: I downloaded the Executable Jar and it seems to work fine! I linked it to IntelliJ and It worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the installer. I suggest to download the executable jar. It's simpler and smaller.

Provided that you have an installed Java8 runtime in the system, all you need is to double click the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED ON WINDOWS 7:

I was having the same issue. When I double click on scene builder icon it doesn't launch just because it's thread was running in the background I followed following method to solve it.

1) start task manager (ctrl + alt + delete)

2) Click on process tab

3) search for SceneBuilder.exe -> right Click on it -> select End Process Tree.